# Scrapy: how to use the XPath selector on files already downloaded by scrapy/wget?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am following the [Scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). My project involves parsing files already downloaded by Scrapy or wget. I understand that I can use an XPath selector for that but the examples that I have seen so far involve an XPath selector being invoked in the parse method in Scrapy and thus work only on files downloaded by Scrapy. Is there a way that I can use XPath directly on downloaded files? I am a newbie to both Python and Scrapy, so I cannot find a way to invoke XPath in a standalone non-Scrapy Python script.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time scrapy uses [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) as xpath selector backend.

You can use lxml directly on any file.

P.S. https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/selector/lxmlsel.py

You can also construct manually a Response object and feed it to HtmlXPathSelector (not tested):

```
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import TextResponse

body = '<your html page here'
response = TextResponse(url = '', body = body, encoding = 'utf-8')

hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
subcategories = hxs.select("your xpath query here")
print subcategories
```

Comment: Thanks for both the response. But it seems that both lxml and Beautiful Soup are more powerful adn therefore take a longer time to learn. So wondering if there is any way out to use scrapy's pareser

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Beautiful Soup` for parsing the already downloaded files.
Its easier to use

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

I would love to use it even while parsing with scrapy